# jenkins email notification "failed to connect, no password specified"

Tags: jenkins

I use the Jenkins configuration to send email notifications，
The configuration screenshot is as follows

[image]

**There are two very strange things here:**

- the password here is shown in clear text
- the comparison with the online data shows that there is a missing the "Use SMTP Authentication" option here,such as
  [image]

The final build result of my configuration will appear

```
[Pipeline] emailext
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Adding recipients from project recipient list
Analyzing: 2294625664@qq.com
Looking for: 2294625664@qq.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: 2294625664@qq.com
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: 2294625664@qq.com
Looking for: 2294625664@qq.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: 2294625664@qq.com
    => found type: 0
Analyzing: 2294625664@qq.com
Looking for: 2294625664@qq.com
    starting at: 0
    firstFoundIdx: 0
    firstFoundIdx-substring: 2294625664@qq.com
    => found type: 0
Adding recipients from trigger recipient list
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: 2294625664@qq.com
*MessagingException message: failed to connect, no password specified?*
[Pipeline] echo
```

***my app version:***

- jenkins:2.235.2
- the plugin 'Email Extension Plugin' : '2.73'
- the plugin 'Email Extension Template Plugin': '1.1'

Please help me with this problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem this week.

You can do what Antala Ashik says. I deleted plugin 2.73 and installed 2.69

- Go to this link: https://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/email-ext/
- Download the HPI file
- Go to Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Manage Plugins > Advanced
- Scroll down to Upload Plugin section and select the HPI file
- Restart

It should be working now.

Or you can follow the link below. You can use a Groovy script to set your configurations. It seems to be possible workaround.

https://nickcharlton.net/posts/configuring-jenkins-email-ext-plugin-groovy.html

Answer (score 3):

Replace your 'Email Extension' Plugin version with "2.69"